# Calculating c and n0

Tags: big-o

I have a quiz in my course where a question goes: ”We have found out that f(n) = 7n^2+3n+8. This means that the function is of O(???) and that c = ??? and n0 = ???”

I know that O(n^2), but I’ve searched every source imaginable in order to find out how to calculate c and n0. In some threads here I reckon that you can pick a value for n0 and then compute c with the given value for n0, but I assume my question requires specific (i.e. correct) values for c and n0 since there seems to be only one right answer in the questions in the quiz.

Comment: What are the options to your question in quiz as with that you can very easily verify if c and n0 makes n^2 as upper bound or not

Comment: There are no options for the answers I'm afraid, it is type in answers

Answer (score 4):

Big-O notation will tell that certain function will not exceed simpler function beyond constant multiple (c) and for large values of n(n0).
As we all know that 7n^2+3n +8  is O(n^2) as for large values of n, 3n +8 will be insignificant. So we need to c and n0 such that

```
7n^2 + 3n + 8 <= cn^2  for all n >= n0
```

Dividing by n^2 will give us :

```
7 + 3/n + 8/n^2 <= c for all n >=  n0
```

if we choose n0 = 1 we will get

```
7 + 3 + 8 <= c
```

so we can set c = 18 and n0 = 1 this can be one of the solutions which means

```
7n^2 + 3n + 8 <= 18n^2 for all n >= 1
```

Also I believe there can never be one solution for this answer.

Comment: should be 18n^2

Comment: In that case i don't feel that stupid anymore. Thanks